# Why is my Gradle Failing on my Unity Android Build?

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I used to use 'Internal' option to build my Android Version but in Unity 2019 there is no option.

When trying to build my Android version I get the following errors:

D8: Program type already present: 
android.support.annotation.FractionRes
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 19s

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :extractProguardFiles
>
> Task :CropLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :CropLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :CropLib:checkReleaseManifest
>
> Task :CropLib:processReleaseManifest
>
> Task :Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
>
> Task :Firebase:processReleaseManifest
>
> Task :preReleaseBuild
>
> Task :CropLib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :CropLib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :checkReleaseManifest
>
> Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
>
> Task :prepareLintJar
>
> Task :generateReleaseSources
>
> Task :CropLib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :CropLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>
> Task :CropLib:generateReleaseResValues
>
> Task :CropLib:generateReleaseResources
>
> Task :CropLib:packageReleaseResources
>
> Task :CropLib:generateReleaseRFile
>
> Task :CropLib:prepareLintJar
>
> Task :CropLib:generateReleaseSources
>
> Task :CropLib:javaPreCompileRelease
>
> Task :CropLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :CropLib:bundleLibCompileRelease
>
> Task :Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>
> Task :Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>
> Task :Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
>
> Task :Firebase:generateReleaseResources
>
> Task :Firebase:packageReleaseResources
>
> Task :Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
>
> Task :Firebase:prepareLintJar
>
> Task :Firebase:generateReleaseSources
>
> Task :Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
>
> Task :Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>
> Task :Firebase:bundleLibCompileRelease
>
> Task :javaPreCompileRelease
>
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
>
> Task :generateReleaseResValues
>
> Task :generateReleaseResources
>
> Task :mergeReleaseResources
>
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
>
> Task :processReleaseManifest

/Users/spin/Desktop/Yellows Unity App - Android

2019/Temp/gradleOut/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
    activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
warn: removing resource com.Yellows.Monthly:string/save without required default value.

> Task :processReleaseResources
>   Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :compileReleaseSources
>   Task :CropLib:prepareLintJarForPublish
>   Task :Firebase:prepareLintJarForPublish
>   Task :lintVitalRelease
>   Task :mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :CropLib:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :CropLib:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :CropLib:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :mergeReleaseAssets
>   Task :validateSigningRelease
>   Task :signingConfigWriterRelease
>   Task :processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :Firebase:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   Task :CropLib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :CropLib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
>   Task :Firebase:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :Firebase:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
>   Task :transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED
>   R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
>   https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
>   disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
>   Current version is: 1.4.77 (build b74371231cb896b02f83285efb055b7c00ff64d8 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-eqqf)).
>   Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>   55 actionable tasks: 55 executed
>   CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
>   /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/OpenJDK/MacOS/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2019.2.0f1/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
D8: Program type already present: android.support.annotation.FractionRes

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.

  > com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
]
stdout[

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :extractProguardFiles
>   Task :CropLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CropLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :CropLib:checkReleaseManifest
>   Task :CropLib:processReleaseManifest
>   Task :Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
>   Task :Firebase:processReleaseManifest
>   Task :preReleaseBuild
>   Task :CropLib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :Firebase:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :checkReleaseManifest
>   Task :generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   Task :prepareLintJar
>   Task :generateReleaseSources
>   Task :CropLib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseResValues
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseResources
>   Task :CropLib:packageReleaseResources
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseRFile
>   Task :CropLib:prepareLintJar
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseSources
>   Task :CropLib:javaPreCompileRelease
>   Task :CropLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :CropLib:bundleLibCompileRelease
>   Task :Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseResources
>   Task :Firebase:packageReleaseResources
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseRFile
>   Task :Firebase:prepareLintJar
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseSources
>   Task :Firebase:javaPreCompileRelease
>   Task :Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :Firebase:bundleLibCompileRelease
>   Task :javaPreCompileRelease
>   Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease
>   Task :generateReleaseResValues
>   Task :generateReleaseResources
>   Task :mergeReleaseResources
>   Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests
>
> Task :processReleaseManifest
>   /Users/spin/Desktop/Yellows Unity App - Android 2019/Temp/gradleOut/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31:50 Warning:
>       activity#com.google.firebase.auth.internal.FederatedSignInActivity@android:launchMode was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:24 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present
>   warn: removing resource com.Yellows.Monthly:string/save without required default value.
>
> Task :processReleaseResources
>   Task :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
>   Task :compileReleaseSources
>   Task :CropLib:prepareLintJarForPublish
>   Task :Firebase:prepareLintJarForPublish
>   Task :lintVitalRelease
>   Task :mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :CropLib:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :CropLib:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :CropLib:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :CropLib:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
>   Task :Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
>   Task :Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
>   Task :Firebase:packageReleaseAssets
>   Task :mergeReleaseAssets
>   Task :validateSigningRelease
>   Task :signingConfigWriterRelease
>   Task :processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :CropLib:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :Firebase:bundleLibResRelease
>   Task :transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
>   Task :CropLib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :CropLib:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
>   Task :Firebase:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
>   Task :Firebase:mergeReleaseConsumerProguardFiles
>
> Task :transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease FAILED
>   R8 is the new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
>   https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
>   disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
>   Current version is: 1.4.77 (build b74371231cb896b02f83285efb055b7c00ff64d8 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-eqqf)).

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
55 actionable tasks: 55 executed
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <8277255796414cc8b8865316c1676de5>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:281)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Build completed with a result of 'Failed'

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 114 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're including the symbol `android.support.annotation.FractionRes` multiple times (see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/FractionRes)).

My first guess is that you used to explode the JARs and now they're just included in your gradle file. You might want to clear out `Assets/Plugins/Android` (especially if it's filled with jar files) and force run the play services resolver afterwards. See [this](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef).

My second guess is that this has to do with the support library to androidx migration Firebase underwent in [June](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2019-06-17). In this case, there are a few things you can do to resolve the issue.

First, make sure that you have the [latest](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) (6.5.0 as of right now) Unity SDK. Back in July, [updates were made](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#version_620_-_july_2_2019) that fix these sorts of issues specifically.

Next, look at your play services resolver settings and make sure `Patch mainTemplate.gradle` and `Use Jetifier` are selected. Especially if you do have a `mainTemplate.gradle` file, this will help resolve some issues.
[image: sample Android Resolver Settings]

I've written up some information about the Play Services Resolver [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef), which I also linked above.

I hope something here helps!

--Patrick

Comment: I found the issue. I have these 2 files after resolving: 'android-support-v4' , 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0'. When I delete 'android-support-v4' I can build and run the apk. The problem is the CamerShot Unity plugin needs 'android-support-v4' to run. Any ideas what to do now? (If you download CameraShot you will see it comes with 'android-support-v4'. But the resolver added com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0 to my project)

Comment: I don't know how camera shot patches the Gradle file. If you can disable its process, I'd recommend writing the dependencies in a Dependencies.xml file as I outline here: https://link.medium.com/uHkAbEvGj0

Comment: I have contacted the Camerashot developer, I appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Library `com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0` should only exist once in the package:

```
implementation ("com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support", module: "support-annotations"
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. But there is Camera component that uses 'android-support-v4'. So I have these 2 libraries 'com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0' - they conflict. Firebase uses com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0. I see reference by the Camera in my manifest android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider". Maybe I can update the manifest to reflect com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0?

Comment: This is the manifest:  <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.Yellows.cameratest.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>

Answer (score 0):

- What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease'.FAILED

if you using below lines in progaurd-project file, then comment them and Generate release build again.
-injars      bin/classes
-injars      libs

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Can you clarify further...I do not understand. Thanks!